# onicegatheringstatechange event does not trigger during candidates gathering

Tags: webrtc

I am writing a webrtc application where I can not use trickle ice. So I am waiting for ICE candidates gathering to complete and send the offer to other peer so that ICE candidates are included in SDP. I have set an event handle for onicegatheringstatechange and waiting for iceGatheringState to change. But this event is not triggered.

```
pc = new RTCPeerConnection(peerConnectionConfig, peerConnectionConstraints);
pc.onicegatheringstatechange = onIceGatheringStateChange;
```

Is there something else I have to do in order to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't wait for onicegatheringstatechange to be called.

This is what you should be doing:

1. Use the onicecandidate function to receive the ice candidates.
2. When you receive the "null" event, you know all candidates were received.
3. If the "null" event is not received passed a timer, proceed with the call anyway.

Here is a rough example for your code (use it as a template only):

```
 var timer; // Some globally accessible timer variable
 var state = "not sent"; // Keep track of call state

 pc.onicecandidate = function(event) {

   if (!event.candidate) {
     // last candidate received. Check if SDP was already sent.
     if(state != "sent"){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        // Send SDP to remote peer:
        // Send pc.localDescription
        // Change call state to "sent"
     }
   }else{
     // Start a timer for the max "wait" time for ice candidates.
     timer = setTimeout(function(){
        // Ice gathering too slow, send SDP anyway.
        // Send pc.localDescription
        // Change call state to "sent"
     }, 1000);
   }
 }
```

It is important for you to use the onicecandidate event with a timer because in the event of you using multiple Stun and Turn servers, the ice gathering process can take many seconds, especially before receiving the "null" event. With this technique, you can even wait for a specific amount of candidates before proceeding with the call as you don't need all the candidates to generate a proper SDP for your application. There's also ways to improve this method by starting a very small timer in between each ice candidate received.

In this example, I set a timer with a max delay of 1000ms because I assume the browser has received an acceptable ice candidate at this point. It is up to you to test and see what is the best user experience.

Comment: Thanks @syno. I was doing it using the way you mentioned. I was think to use the gathering states for this purpose.